# Error reading JObect from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object -- running node.js program

Tags: node.js, fetch-api

This error is slightly different than the others I've seen: this one comes from a node.js program. Here is the program I'm trying to run:

```
const token = "abc123_samplefaketoken"
const request = "https://api.maximizer.com/octopus/abEntryRead";
const auth = "Bearer " + token;
const payload = {
    "abEntry": {
        "criteria": {
            "searchQuery": {
                "LastName": {
                    "$EQ": "."
                }
            },
            "top": "15"
        },
        "scope": {
            "fields": {
                "key": "1",
                "type": "1",
                "webSite": "1",
                "displayValue": "1"
            }
        }
    },
    "configuration": {
        "drivers": {
            "IAbEntrySearcher": "Maximizer.Model.Access.Sql.AbEntrySearcher"
        }
    },
    "compatibility": {
        "abEntryKey": "2.0"
    }
};

const maxConnectOptions = { method: "POST", redirect: "follow", headers: { Authorization: auth }, body: payload };

fetch(request, maxConnectOptions)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((resultset) => console.log(resultset))
    .catch((error) => console.log("Error: " + error));
```

Here is the full error message when I run this program via node.js:

```
{
  Code: -1,
  Msg: [
    {
      Message: "Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.",
      ErrorCode: 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Any suggestions?

The real/true token does work (I tested it for connectivity to the source and it was successful).

It looks like the fetch API is working as it should (but I can't tell) but I'm concerned that my payload is not correctly formatted for JSON (hence the error).

Running the same payload via Postman to the API source with the correct/true token is successful.

Answer (score 0):

After researching some more, I figured out why this error is coming up: I never specified a Content-Type value of "application/json". The default content type, I suppose, is application/text. After specifying updating the "headers" property to:

```
{"Content-Type: "application/json", "Authorization": "Bearer " + token}
```

My program started working!